# Explicit return type based on arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Given a function which takes an array of objects, and returns an object whose keys all correspond to a property on each of the objects in the argument... it seems like there should be a way to get a more explicit return type.

The function-

```
function objectFromArray(arr: { key: string }[]) {
    let obj: {[k: string]: true} = {};
    for (let {key} of arr) {
        obj[key] = true;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

If I run the following

```
let myArray = [{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}, {key: 'c'}];
let myObj = objectFromArray(myArray);
```

Then the type of `myObj` is

```
let myObj: {
    [k: string]: true;
}
```

But I feel like enough information is present in order for typescript infer that the type of `myObj` is in fact

```
let myObj: {
    a: true;
    b: true;
    c: true;
}
```

My question is what needs to be done in the `objectFromArray` function in order to derive the explicit return type based on the argument. For clarity, I'm not worried about the values of the return type, just worried about getting the explicit keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want that to work you need `objectFromArray()` to be a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#generic-functions) in the type `K` of the [string literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) values at the `key` property of the `arr` elements:

```
function objectFromArray<K extends string>(arr: readonly { key: K }[]) {
  let obj = {} as { [P in K]: true }; // have to assert this because it's not true yet
  for (let { key } of arr) {
    obj[key] = true;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

The `readonly` in `readonly { key: K }[]` just means that we don't specifically require the passed-in array to be mutable.  This allows more leeway for the input, which we'll need in a bit.

The return type, `{ [P in K]: true }` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) giving an object with a `true`-valued property for each string literal type in `K`.  (You could also use the [`Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) to give the equivalent `Record<K, true>`).  Since `{}` is not a valid value of this type, you'll need a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) to tell the compiler to treat `obj` as type `{ [P in K]: true }`.

---

Then when you create `myArray`, the default behavior of the compiler is to widen its type to `Array<{key: string}>`, completely forgetting about the string literal types `"a"`, `"b"`, and `"c"`.  To prevent this you can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
let myArray = [{ key: 'a' }, { key: 'b' }, { key: 'c' }] as const;

/* let myArray: readonly [{
    readonly key: "a";
}, {
    readonly key: "b";
}, {
    readonly key: "c";
}] */
```

Notice how the `const` assertion makes `myArray` a `readonly` array, which is why loosening the function's input type is useful. Now that the compiler knows enough about `myArray`, let's call `objectFromArray()`:

```
let myObj = objectFromArray(myArray);
/* let myObj: {
    a: true;
    b: true;
    c: true;
} */
```

Success!  `myObj` is known to have `a`, `b`, and `c` properties of type `true`, as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABHARgKwKbQGICc4C2AgrrgIYCeAPANKIYAeUGYAJgM6LtS4xgDmAPgAUZUgC5EuDGVYIANhUQBvRAGsMFSXQC+AbQC6AShUAoRInkYoydIgC8KnYjKdVegAqI+iGgck8IBiIOgDciAD0EYgAFmQAbsFQcC7s7Bi4NlAxMJwoWGQg6d5QAOScYHBZuEGIFNbmiMBwuIjCVjaqGkrOcMAupCbKjRaoaHrdBg6IgRihjTqN0lAguEhj84umHYgEFCTkSo56XZqSpWSlIQA0KupniKUoVzq3p1qPEC9TrogQCNx5hEAFSWay7fakSiSaSyBRKE4jKQyORgRT3D4AIjImM2byRsNR6O6kkxKFxpleZgsFkJ8IxpIgFJ0U2BEVM23BewA8nZHGMsFA8IQDpRhHtRRQjEDQTseehJMMaS4AjU5kiUKqgvNlRAternGyOUA)